# Dropbox API: how can I get the amount of remaining free space?

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

It seems to me that the Dropbox API lacks the ability to tell the remaining available free space for the linked Dropbox account. I can only get the total quota of the user, by using the .accountInfo() call.

The only way I see is to iterate over all the files the user stores in Dropbox, and sum up their sizes, then subtract this amount from the total quota. This solutions seems quite terrible and slow, is there a better way to this?

As a sidenote, I attempt to do this on Android, but I don't think that this is a platfrom-dependent question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation for the /account/info call](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#account-info) state:

> quota_info/normal The user's used quota outside of shared folders (bytes).
>
> quota_info/shared The user's used quota in shared folders (bytes).
>
> quota_info/quota  The user's total quota allocation (bytes).

So, the free space should just be:

```
quota - normal - shared
```

Comment: not so related, but do you know how to do it with the Sync API?

Comment: DbxAccountInfo getAccountInfo() for Android Sync SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/android#com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccount or DBAccountInfo *info for iOS Sync SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBAccount

Comment: DbxAccountInfo provides info about display name and email, but nothing about free space and total space :( Thank you anyway!!

Comment: I'm wondering how to get quota info using the Sync API as well. JesusS, did you ever figure that out?

Comment: no infos with sync api... you will have to use another api