# how to get available space in BOX android api?

Tags: java, android, box-api

I am trying to get Total Storage and Available Storage of BOX user but i didn't found anything on BOX android API
I found it is possible for Dropbox [here is solution for Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853410/dropbox-api-how-can-i-get-the-amount-of-remaining-free-space) but didn't found anything related to BOX android api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found solution using UserManager

Get used space and total space in Mb

```
client.getUsersManager().getCurrentUser(null).getSpaceUsed() / 1048576
client.getUsersManager().getCurrentUser(null).getSpaceAmount() / 1048576
```